# Building a gui app using wxPython (menubars)

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

while creating a menubar and adding menu-items to it,my panel is showing blank...the menubar is not showing and am getting this message-
 (python:4106): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

how do i resolve this problem???

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a bit late but...

Are you using Ubuntu 11/12? It's a bug in Ubuntu's GTK implementation from what I gathered

There are unofficial patches but they are for C++ Wx. I have the same problem as you and it is annoying
http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/14292

For myself, the menu bar shows itself but the signals aren't sent to the status bar when going over it with the mouse.

I removed the "global menu bar" from Unity using the link on the ticket. It fixed the problem

Comment: Could I know why I got a negative feedback?

Answer (score 0):

We kind of need a sample app: http://wiki.wxpython.org/MakingSampleApps That will help us figure out the issue. However, menus are supposed to be children of the frame in almost all cases, so I suspect that is your problem. Attach it to the frame instead of the panel. See also http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/07/02/wxpython-working-with-menus-toolbars-and-accelerators/ or http://zetcode.com/wxpython/menustoolbars/