# wxPython 2.8.12.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 - Why menu icon is not displayed?

Tags: python, ubuntu, wxpython

I borrowed an example code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078661/wxpython-menu-doesnt-display-image) and altered it for my purpose:

```
import wx

def getBmp():
    bmp = wx.EmptyBitmapRGBA(16,16, red=100, green=50, blue=50)
    return bmp

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, parent=None)

        self.SetTitle("why No image?")

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        item = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_NEW, "New")
        item.SetBitmap(getBmp())
        item = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "Open")
        item.SetBitmap(getBmp())
        item = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "Save")
        item.SetBitmap(getBmp())
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = MyFrame()
frame.Show()
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
app.MainLoop()
```

**Problem**: On my system configuration (Ubuntu 12.04 and wxPython 2.8.12.1) there is no icon/bitmap being displayed for any of the menu entries. No error messages except when I close down the window:

*(python:3321): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING ***: *Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Unity takes all menubars and puts them in the Global menu - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2004101

These two links discuss the issue a bit more:

- [Building a gui app using wxPython (menubars)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679421/building-a-gui-app-using-wxpython-menubars)
- [LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598159/libdbusmenu-glib-warning)

The last one has a solution for removing the menubars in such a way that you won't see the error anymore, but it doesn't sound like it works in a cross-platform manner.

Comment: In addition, there is a Gnome preference that controls whether menu items will show their icons or not.  Ubuntus from the last few years have defaulted to having that option turned off.